# Error text is not being displayed for function result

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

I've successfully used the definition on other pages before. Basically it should make the field required, but fail if only whitespace is entered (by default typing i.e. a single space causes the required check to pass). I tossed an alert in just to see when the handler is fired as well as the value of `this` at that time. It's fired when I expect it, and the value is as I expect it. It should be returning `false` but apparently it isn't because the error isn't being displayed. If I remove that `depends` function and just have `required: true`, it correctly displays the error when the user leaves the field. What's going on?

```
ContactName: {
        required: {
            depends: function() {
                alert("'" + $(this).val() + "'");
                if ($.trim($(this).val()).length === 0) {
                    $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        },
        maxlength: 100
    }
```

Comment: So what is the value of `$.trim($(this).val()).length`?

Comment: @u_mulder 0, my dude.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the rule for **ContactName** like (for details take a look to [rules examples](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules)):

```
ContactName: {
    required: true,
    minlength: {
        depends: function(ele) {
            if (ele.value.trim().length === 0) {
                ele.value = '';
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    },
    maxlength: 100
}
```

The snippet:

```js
$("#commentForm").validate({
    rules: {
        ContactName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: {
                depends: function(ele) {
                    if (ele.value.trim().length === 0) {
                        ele.value = '';
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            },
            maxlength: 100
        }
    },
    messages: {
        ContactName: "Please enter your contact name"
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <label for="ContactName">Name</label>
            <input id="ContactName" name="ContactName" type="text">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```